# how to rename multiple files from different subfolders in R, while keeping them in their original folder

Tags: r, loops, subdirectory, file-rename

```
'''
    
fieldszn <- '~/Desktop/hls project/fieldszn'
bands <- list.files(fieldszn, pattern = "*.tiff", recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE)
new_names <- c("red", "nir", "fmask")
file.rename(bands, paste0(new_names,"*.tiff"))
        
red <- list.files(subfolders, pattern = "red.tiff", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
    
nir <- list.files(subfolders, pattern = "nir.tiff", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
    
redstack <- stack(red)
    
nirstack <- stack(nir)
    
ndvi <- overlay(redstack, nirstack, fun = function(x,y) {
      (y - x)/(y +x)
      })
    
writeRaster(ndvi, paste0(subfolders,'NDVI',i,'.tif'))

,,,
```

i currently have 9 different sub-folders, with 3 raster bands per sub-folder that present an individual image (all of which are in the format of a asset link that includes granule id, satellite type, etc.). i'm trying to iterate through them to rename to a common name like red, nir, and fmask, so i can then iterate them through to run through a vegetation index calculation. i've been able to rename them but they keep ending up into the working directory rather than their original folder and i haven't figured out how to iterate through them without adding a number to them.

after renaming the files, i'm planning to iterate them through a vegetation index calculation - but i'm not sure how to set it up.

please help! i'm new to R and would appreciate any assistance.

[visual of the raster band structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjSiW.png)

[current file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRiTP.png)

[error with pathway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8nWG.png)

[the issue of automated save in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ71r.png)

Comment: i've added the code - attached images also show more! @nostromo

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Some reasons not to attach code as images are given here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: gotcha! @shaun_m i've added the code chunk properly now, but i did include photos of my file structure if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't have the folder path included in the new file names, so file.rename is moving the files to your working directory by default.

You can use `file.path()` to combine paths and filenames.

```
new_names <- file.path(dirname(bands), paste0(c("red", "nir", "fmask"), ".tiff"))
file.rename(bands, new_names)
```

Comment: that's what i was thinking @shaun_m, but within that fieldszn folder it splits into three folders that represent the year, so y21, y22, and y23 - and then within each of those year folders there's three folders per that represent the time of year, so bg, ag, and eog - within each of those is 3 raster bands that represent a single image. so i'm trying to rename each of those bands by iterating through them - i couldn't quite figure out how to specify a vague pathway. i just don't understand why renaming them would move them from their original folder rather than leaving it.

Comment: @shuan_m i've added an image of the error i'm getting with the pathway set up

Comment: @codenoob, I didn't spot the `recursive = TRUE` in your original code. I've edited the answer to use `dirname(bands)` which I hope will produce the result you need.

Comment: THANK YOU @shaun_m! it worked. by adding that dirname() function to the file.path() - it kept the files in the original subfolder as well as changing the full.names variable to = TRUE rather than = FALSE to get rid of the error mentioned above

Comment: any suggestions on how to set up that NDVI calculation to iterate through each of those files to spit out an ndvi.tiff for each combination of bands?

Comment: i tried to set it up as a stack as well as a for loop, but i can't get results - would you have any suggestions on how to format it and save the results?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with NDVI calculations, but my very rough understanding is that you need to use the three .tiff files in each folder to create a new ndvi.tiff. The broad approach I would suggest is: 1. Create a function (e.g. `make_ndvi(folder_path)`) which takes a folder name and then reads the 3 files, processes them and outputs a tiff in the same folder. 2. get the list of folders (`folders <- unique(dirname(bands))`). 3. use lapply to run the function on all folders (`lapply(folders, make_ndvi)`). If you need further help on this, then you should create a new question.